# Case statements, subqueries, DATEPART function, DATENAME function

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

I need to construct a query to find the following information from the below tables using SQL:

**Find the names of the different passengers who have ever flown a flight which took off on Saturday and landed on Sunday.**

Here are the tables in the database schema:

```
Company table

ID_comp name
------------

1   Don_avia  
2   Aeroflot  
3   Dale_avia 
4   air_France
5   British_AW



Passenger table

ID_psg name
-----------

1   Bruce Willis        
2   George Clooney      
3   Kevin Costner       
4   Donald Sutherland   
5   Jennifer Lopez      
6   Ray Liotta          
7   Samuel L. Jackson   
8   Nikole Kidman       
9   Alan Rickman        
10  Kurt Russell        
11  Harrison Ford       
12  Russell Crowe       
13  Steve Martin        
14  Michael Caine       
15  Angelina Jolie      
16  Mel Gibson          
17  Michael Douglas     
18  John Travolta       
19  Sylvester Stallone  
20  Tommy Lee Jones     
21  Catherine Zeta-Jones
22  Antonio Banderas    
23  Kim Basinger        
24  Sam Neill           
25  Gary Oldman         
26  Clint Eastwood      
27  Brad Pitt           
28  Johnny Depp         
29  Pierce Brosnan      
30  Sean Connery        
31  Bruce Willis        
37  Mullah Omar    

Pass_in_trip table

trip_no date                  ID_psg place
-------------------------

1100    2003-04-29 00:00:00.000 1   1a        
1123    2003-04-05 00:00:00.000 3   2a        
1123    2003-04-08 00:00:00.000 1   4c        
1123    2003-04-08 00:00:00.000 6   4b        
1124    2003-04-02 00:00:00.000 2   2d        
1145    2003-04-05 00:00:00.000 3   2c        
1145    2003-04-25 00:00:00.000 5   1d        
1181    2003-04-01 00:00:00.000 1   1a        
1181    2003-04-01 00:00:00.000 6   1b        
1181    2003-04-01 00:00:00.000 8   3c        
1181    2003-04-13 00:00:00.000 5   1b        
1182    2003-04-13 00:00:00.000 5   4b        
1182    2003-04-13 00:00:00.000 9   6d        
1187    2003-04-14 00:00:00.000 8   3a        
1187    2003-04-14 00:00:00.000 10  3d        
1188    2003-04-01 00:00:00.000 8   3a        
7771    2005-11-04 00:00:00.000 11  4a        
7771    2005-11-07 00:00:00.000 11  1b        
7771    2005-11-07 00:00:00.000 37  1c        
7771    2005-11-09 00:00:00.000 11  5a        
7771    2005-11-14 00:00:00.000 14  4d        
7771    2005-11-16 00:00:00.000 14  5d        
7772    2005-11-07 00:00:00.000 12  1d        
7772    2005-11-07 00:00:00.000 37  1a        
7772    2005-11-29 00:00:00.000 10  3a        
7772    2005-11-29 00:00:00.000 13  1b        
7772    2005-11-29 00:00:00.000 14  1c        
7773    2005-11-07 00:00:00.000 13  2d        
7778    2005-11-05 00:00:00.000 10  2a        
8881    2005-11-08 00:00:00.000 37  1d        
8882    2005-11-06 00:00:00.000 37  1a        
8882    2005-11-13 00:00:00.000 14  3d  


Trip table

trip_no ID_comp plane town_from town_to time_out time_in
--------------------------------------------------------

1100    4   Boeing      Rostov      Paris       1900-01-01 14:30:00.000  1900-01-01 17:50:00.000
1101    4   Boeing      Paris       Rostov      1900-01-01 08:12:00.000  1900-01-01 11:45:00.000
1123    3   TU-154      Rostov      Vladivostok 1900-01-01 16:20:00.000  1900-01-01 03:40:00.000
1124    3   TU-154      Vladivostok Rostov      1900-01-01 09:00:00.000  1900-01-01 19:50:00.000
1145    2   IL-86       Moscow      Rostov      1900-01-01 09:35:00.000  1900-01-01 11:23:00.000
1146    2   IL-86       Rostov      Moscow      1900-01-01 17:55:00.000 1900-01-01 20:01:00.000
1181    1   TU-134      Rostov      Moscow      1900-01-01 06:12:00.000 1900-01-01 08:01:00.000
1182    1   TU-134      Moscow      Rostov      1900-01-01 12:35:00.000 1900-01-01 14:30:00.000
1187    1   TU-134      Rostov      Moscow      1900-01-01 15:42:00.000 1900-01-01 17:39:00.000
1188    1   TU-134      Moscow      Rostov      1900-01-01 22:50:00.000 1900-01-01 00:48:00.000
1195    1   TU-154      Rostov      Moscow      1900-01-01 23:30:00.000 1900-01-01 01:11:00.000
1196    1   TU-154      Moscow      Rostov      1900-01-01 04:00:00.000 1900-01-01 05:45:00.000
7771    5   Boeing      London      Singapore   1900-01-01 01:00:00.000 1900-01-01 11:00:00.000
7772    5   Boeing      Singapore   London      1900-01-01 12:00:00.000 1900-01-01 02:00:00.000
7773    5   Boeing      London      Singapore   1900-01-01 03:00:00.000 1900-01-01 13:00:00.000
7774    5   Boeing      Singapore   London      1900-01-01 14:00:00.000 1900-01-01 06:00:00.000
7775    5   Boeing      London      Singapore   1900-01-01 09:00:00.000 1900-01-01 20:00:00.000
7776    5   Boeing      Singapore   London      1900-01-01 18:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:00:00.000
7777    5   Boeing      London      Singapore   1900-01-01 18:00:00.000 1900-01-01 06:00:00.000
7778    5   Boeing      Singapore   London      1900-01-01 22:00:00.000 1900-01-01 12:00:00.000
8881    5   Boeing      London      Paris       1900-01-01 03:00:00.000 1900-01-01 04:00:00.000
8882    5   Boeing      Paris       London      1900-01-01 22:00:00.000 1900-01-01 23:00:00.000
```

Any suggestions on how to format the last table would be appreciated as well, I have been trying to fix it for the past hour!

Comment: Are you asking about MS SQL or Oracle? They use different functions etc.

Comment: Can u provide a sqlfiddle on above tables?

Comment: Actually both, but I am testing my solutions on an Oracle database.

Comment: And I am working on providing a SQLfiddle - I keep getting the error "Unknown Error Occurred: Premature end of file.:" - will post when I have an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that no flight takes more than 24 hours at the most all we need to do is to find the flights that started of Saturdays and have a `time_in` value before the `time_out`. With MSSQL it could look like this:

```
select p.name
from Pass_in_trip pit
join Trip t on t.trip_no = pit.trip_no
join Passenger p on pit.ID_psg = p.ID_psg
where DATENAME(dw, pit.date) = 'Saturday'
and t.time_in < t.time_out
```

With your sample data this would return:

```
Kevin Costner
Kurt Russell
```

Of course, if a trip could take more than 24 hours it would be impossible to determine with certainty that the flight took place between two dates as the data model doesn't record this.

For **Oracle** you can do the weekday check like this `to_char(date, 'DAY') = 'Saturday'` I think - I haven't been able to test it though.

Comment: This is returning the correct result, but for some reason this is what I am getting *along with* the correct result:                   "Wrong.
Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database
* Wrong number of records (more by 1)
NAME
Kevin Costner       
Kurt Russell

Comment: but the logic is sound, so I will go with it. Thank you.